# Different behaviour of shiny::textOutput when wrapped inside p and h HTML tags

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I'm trying to understand why `p` and `h` tags lead to different behaviour when used to wrap `textOutput` functions. I'm not sure whether this is Shiny-specific behaviour or a wider HTML thing.

In the following minimal example there are two `textOutput`s (imagine that they are reactive, there's just no need to add the reactivity to this example). One is wrapped in an `h4` tag, while the other is wrapped in a `p` tag. The ultimate aim is to add CSS styles to the outputs.

Outside of a reactive environment, I would normally just do it like this: `p(id = "great_style", ...)`. This will apply the `#great_style` CSS to everything in the `p` tag. The thing is, when we instead wrap the `p` tag around a `textOutput`, Shiny creates an empty `p` tag (with any `id` arguments, etc.), and then underneath that creates a `div` with the `textOutput`:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- {
    fluidPage(
        fluidRow(
            h4(textOutput('h4')),
            p(id = "great_style", textOutput('p'))
        )
    )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$h4 <- renderText({
        "This text will be rendered within the h4-tag"
    })
    
    output$p <- renderText({
        "But this text is rendered outside of the p-tag, in a new div"
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This only occurs for the `p` tag; the `h4` tag does not create a new, empty tag:

[image: html]

I'm not too fussed about fixing the issue, because if we wrap the `textOutput` in a `div` we can style it just fine, e.g.:

```
fluidRow(
    h4(textOutput('h4')),
    div(id = "great_style", textOutput('p'))
)
```

I'm just more curious about why this is the case. Is there a way to wrap a `p` tag around a reactive `textOutput` in Shiny?

Comment: For a reactive textOutput, should the p tag not be on the server side?

Comment: you cannot have div inside p